# How to override a private method from a different library in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a class like so:

```
class A {
  int _foo () {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

I have another class that extends the above and overrides the private method:

```
class B extends A {
  @override
  int _foo() {
    return super._foo() + 1;
  }
}
```

This works as expected when `B` is in the same library as `A`.
But when they are in different files, it seems like I cannot override `_foo()` or call `super._foo()`.

What is a workaround for this? Is this even possible?

Note my real use-case is that `A` is a 3rd party library, and I want to override a private method.

Comment: You cannot override private methods in another library.

Comment: Not even with extensions?

Comment: Dart extensions are syntactic sugar.  They don't allow you to fundamentally do anything that a freestanding function can't do.  While you could create an extension method that happens to have the same name as an existing private method, existing callers within that class's library won't magically use it.

Comment: Ok. Just make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally you cannot override private methods of libraries.
There are some alternative hacks you can go with.
**1)** Copy the package folder in your current code and change it as per your need.
**2)** Create a public method in library class and pass that private method in it. You can have the access of that private method as defined public method.
**3)** Example Code:

```
class A {
  String toString() => _p();
  String _p() => 'A';
}

class B extends A {
  String _p() => 'B';
}

void main() {
  print(new A());
  print(new B());
}
```

I hope this [referance](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/12600) and [ongoing conversations](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/XZ0pqeqCeVs/discussion) will surely help. :).